# Filing for unemployment after quitting a W2 job for a 1099 contractor role?

Tags: united-states, unemployment, texas

My wife left her W2 job for a 1099 contractor role last month. She was fired from the 1099 contractor role for underperforming after 3 weeks. When filling out the unemployment information for Texas, it only asks for her last job which was only for 3 weeks. Should she fill out the forms for her 1099 role, or just act like it never happened? The problem is, she *left* her W2 job which would mean she isn't entitled to unemployment benefits for that right?

I tried calling the Texas Workforce Commision, but I just get a busy signal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure she's not entitled to unemployment. She terminated her last employment arrangement voluntarily. Nothing she did as a contractor can make her eligible for unemployment under most state's rules. I don't know Texas specifically, so I'm not making this an answer.

Comment: A 1099 contractor is not an employee.